# Using Skinshifter's ability when Skinshifter Attacks

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering what happens when I attack with  [Skinshifter](http://magiccards.info/query?q=skinshifter&v=card&s=cname). Imagine the following situation.

I attack with [Skinshifter](http://magiccards.info/query?q=skinshifter&v=card&s=cname) and in the assign blockers phase my opponent blocks Skinshifter with [Runeclaw Bear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221893). Can I say that I use Skinshifter's ability to turn him into a Rhino?

Another situation. My opponent attacks with [Runeclaw Bear](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221893). I block it with my Skinshifter. Can I turn him into a Plant when I assign my blockers?

I assume that Skinshifter haven't used his ability in that turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both those situations would work.  Skinshifter's ability can be used at any time you receive priority(i.e any time you could cast an instant).  After both the Declare Attackers step and the Declare Blockers step, players receive priority.

Comment: Agreed.  The only effects for which you need to worry about "when can I play I this?" are ones that say "May only be played as a sorcery".  Those *can't* be used during combat.